# WordPress - Security test for custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, security

I am building a custom plugin for my client and it is partially based on woocommerce where it will make use of few functions or hooks from woocommerce. Finally I would like to test the security of my plugin. Can anyone suggest me if there is any way to run a security test on custom plugins?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no exact automated scanner solution to perform penetration test against custom plugin. Therefore you should do whole penetration test from beginning. You can use Arachni which is one of the best open-source, free to use web application security scanners.

Answer (score 0):

There are vulnerability testing tools such as [Vega](https://subgraph.com/vega) that you might find useful. OWASP make [ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project), which I quite like. Someone else mentioned [Arachni](http://www.arachni-scanner.com/). Either way vulnerability testing cannot find everything so you should be aware of security measures during development.

Really you should familiarise yourself with the common vulnerabilities (SQL injection, XSS, CSRF), including those in the [OWASP Top 10 Vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) before developing.

The other thing to note is that WP Scan is a penetration testing tool for WordPress, however it focuses more on configuration vulnerabilities and thus will not help you. WPScan also run [WPVulnDB](https://wpvulndb.com) which lists known vulnerabilities in WordPress core files, themes and plugins.